# Create a Scheduled webjob on azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, loopbackjs, strongloop

I need to create a scheduled job for my application. I'm using a loopback framework and azure.

I need to create a scheduling  for delete a some data.

**scheduling.js**

```
    var loopback = require('loopback');
    var app = module.exports = loopback();


    app.models.Mymodel.destroyAll({
                 ...
     },function(err,count) {
         console.log('>Deleted Mymodel data', count);
         });
       }
```

This give me a error on azure webjob log

```
app.models.Mymodel undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't create app again by `var app = module.exports = loopback();`

Just import app by `var app = require('path to server.js');`